# Jquery UI.Datepicker : Display tooltip on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm trying to add tool tip on mouse hover, tooltip should display at bottom of mouse pointer. It alert when I hover on date but unable to bind tooltip.
Here is my **[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/LFvCc/)**

**Js Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#academic_calendar').datepicker({
        minDate:0,      
    });
    $(".ui-state-default").live("mouseenter", function() {
        console.log("Hover");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can refer below link:

        http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#entry-examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery live is deprecated. You need to use .on  or .bind handlers. I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFvCc/5/) with the tooltip.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#academic_calendar').datepicker({
    minDate:0,      
   });

   $(".ui-state-default").on("mouseenter", function() {
     $(this).attr('title', 'This is the hover-over text');  // title attribute will be shown during the hover
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I will take **Vinoth** example one step further, and make sure that I bind the listener to html directly so if the calendar is inserted dynamically in future it also works. Also enable jqueryui tool-tip, like this:

```
$( document ).tooltip();
$('#academic_calendar').datepicker({
minDate:0,      
});
$("html").on("mouseenter",".ui-state-default", function() {
$(this).attr('title', 'This is the hover-over text');
});
```

Version of fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5CB8W/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".ui-state-default").hover(function() {

        alert("Test");  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#academic_calendar').datepicker({
        minDate:0,      
    });
    $(".ui-state-default").on("mouseenter", function() {
        console.log("Hover");
    });
</script>
```

[updated check](http://jsfiddle.net/LFvCc/4/)

Comment: itshould display custom tooltip with style and data from php, does it ?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do it just set the title in HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="#academic_calendar" title="Foo Bar">
```

And use this code with the datepicker to display the info in the tooltip:

```
$("#academic_calendar").datepicker({ minDate: 0 }).tooltip({ show: { delay: 0 }, position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "top center" } });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hansthered/Luvo9zz0/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest way of doing it.

```
 $("img.ui-datepicker-trigger").attr('title', 'Select to display date picker.');
```